# What is the use of in label of utf16Offset(in: )

Tags: ios, swift

I can't understand the **in** label of `utf16Offset(in:)` statement

what the use of this label.

And can anyone explain that,
Is the following statement is right or wrong?

```
let location = textString.range(of: hyperText)?.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: textString)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you code is correct.it means the offset into a string's code units for this index.
for example:

```objectivec
  var textString = "niaddjkdskjdsjdsk"
  let location = textString.range(of: "dd")?.lowerBound.utf16Offset(in: textString)
```

as we know, the bound is (3,_),so the utf16Offset is 3.
Before Swift 4.2,we use `encodedOffset`,now it replace by utf16Offset, they are same behavior[image]